# How to combine heatmap with contour plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two similar three-dimensional, but separate datasets (in different CSV files), where α and δ are the independent variables, and ϕ (first dataset) or a percentage value (second dataset) are the dependent variables. The datasets resemble Pivot tables.

I've already managed to plot a heatmap of the first dataset:

[image: AsIs]

Now I would like to add the percentage values of the second dataset as contour lines. I've done it manually in the following example:

[image: ToBe]

How can I achieve this using Seaborn or Matplotlib?
My code currently is as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";").transpose()
sns.heatmap(
    df,
    cmap="Reds",
    cbar_kws={"label": r'$\phi$'},
    vmin=0.0, vmax=1.2).invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(r'$\delta$', fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `contour`:

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(df2.shape[0])+0.5, 
                  np.arange(df2.shape[1])+0.5, 
                  indexing='ij'
                 )

ax=sns.heatmap(df1)
ax.contour(x,y, df2, levels=[40,80,100])
```